# Drupal 7, query with WHERE and AND

Tags: drupal-7

I would use this query :

```
SELECT g.id_site, g.commune, g.latitude, g.longitude, g.altitude, g.date, g.id_fiche, a.essence, e.nom_espece, e.effectif 
FROM general g, arbre a, espece e
WHERE g.nom = a.nom AND g.id_fiche = e.id_fiche AND g.id_fiche = a.id_fiche
```

with the drupal 7 API. I try this :

```
        $query = db_select('general' ,'g');
        $query -> join ('arbre','a','a.nom = g.nom');
        $query -> join ('espece','e','e.nom = a.nom');
        $query -> fields ('g', array('commune','latitude','longitude','altitude','date','id_fiche'));
        $query -> fields ('a', array('essence'));
        $query -> condition ('g.id_fiche','e.id_fiche','=');
        $query -> condition ('g.id_fiche','a.id_fiche','=');
```

But I get no result :/ the problem is these two lines :

```
        $query -> condition ('g.id_fiche','e.id_fiche','=');
        $query -> condition ('g.id_fiche','a.id_fiche','=');
```

If I comment this two lines, I have a result (but without the WHERE clause). What should I do for properly use the WHERE clause ?

thx =)

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the query issues and focusing on just the answer:

Try This:
 I think you simply have to define all the fields you are actually going to use.
If that still does not work try use the [Where](http://drupal.org/node/310086) Clause

```
$query = db_select('general' ,'g');
$query -> join ('arbre','a','a.nom = g.nom');
$query -> join ('espece','e','e.nom = a.nom');
$query -> fields ('e', array('id_fiche','nom'));
$query -> fields ('g', array('commune','latitude','longitude','altitude','date','id_fiche','nom'));
$query -> fields ('a', array('essence','nom'));
$query -> condition ('g.id_fiche','e.id_fiche','=');
$query -> condition ('g.id_fiche','a.id_fiche','=');
```

Comment: Im sorry, I forget give more information..
My query result I want is : 
commune1 latitude1 longitude1 altitude1 date1 id_fiche1 essence1 nom_espece1 effectif1
commune1 latitude1 longitude1 altitude1 date1 id_fiche1 essence1 nom_espece2 effectif2
...
commune1 latitude1 longitude1 altitude1 date1 id_fiche1 essence1 nom_especeN effectifN
commune2 latitude2 longitude2 altitude2 date2 id_fiche2 essence2 nom_espece1 effectif1
...

Comment: See the fields section of the documentation for adding more fields: http://drupal.org/node/1848352

Answer (score 0):

You can use db_query(), i found this method more usable.